# Positioning two divs on top of a third

Tags: css, html

I'm by no means good at handling CSS and Divs.

Basically I'm looking to make something like this:

[image]
edit: I tried the clear:left; but for some reason my bottom-div is now positioned far away from the other divs. Like this:

[image]

Comment: In regards to your edit, laying out pages with the `outline` property helps out a lot.

Comment: Post your code. Maybe there are margin's. There are thousands of possible reasons for that.

Comment: No margins according to firebug.

Comment: Have you tried my solution? is there a problem with this also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS

```
.top
{
    width: %50;
    float: left;
}
.bottom
{
    clear left;
}
```

Markup

```
<div id="containter">
    <div class="top">HELLO</div>
    <div class="top">HELLO</div>
    <div class="bottom">HELLO</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div style="width:50%; float:left">Hello</div>
<div style="width:50%; float:left">Hello</div>
<div style="clear:left">Hello</div>
```

For margin's and border like in your case, I have to know, if you can work with fixed width.

**edit**

Here an advanced version with paddings, margins and borders:

```
<div class="col">Left</div>
<div class="col right">Right</div>
<div class="full">Bottom</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.col {
    width: 47%;
    float: left;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}


.full {
    clear: both;
}
```

You can have a look at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VQkWp/1/) to see it in action.

Answer (score 2):

its pretty simple with floating divs and a container:

```
<div class="columns">
    <div class="left">
        <!-- left div -->
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <!-- right div -->
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <!-- bottom div -->
</div>
```

Styles:

```
.left {
    float: left;
    width: #number#px;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    width: #number#px;
}
.columns {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Hope this makes sense to you.